# Loop to dispatch a reducer in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a `json` file with an array of Todos that I want to render as an initial state calling my reducer `type: 'ADD_TODO'`. Where is better to loop to `dispatch` the action:

Is better to loop in the Component, adding each single Todo, like:

```
myInitialTodos.forEach(
  (todo, id) => store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id
  })
)
```

or in another `reducer` composed with `ADD_TODO`, like:

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_TODOS',
  todos: myInitialTodos
})
```

In both cases, launching when `componentDidMount` (for example).

Maybe (and most probably) there is another and better way.

Thanks,

Comment: Where are the todos coming from? Is it better to move them from componentDidMount to the initial reducer state?

Comment: Thanks Mike, they could come from an `ajax` request for example (not static)

Comment: Ah, is it possible to send the JSON data with the initial request from the server and bootstrap the data into Redux?

Comment: @Mike my idea is to `dispatch` when the `ajax` request returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its definitely better to add separate action type of ADD_TODOS and pass an array of todos to your reducer. If you think about eventually adding a backend to your react application, you wouldn't want to make a bunch of API calls to add multiple todos, you'd want to send only one network request.

EDIT: Also, if you are always going to want to add the same list of todos to your application to start, the better way is to put them in the initial state that you pass to your reducer, so something like this could do the trick:

```
const initialState = [{title: 'A sample todo', completed: false},{title: 'Another sample todo', completed: false}]

const todos = (state = initialState, action) => { //Reducer logic }
```

Comment: You can also use the same action creator and just convert all single todos into an array: `todos = [todos]`. Then in the reducer you can always expect an array.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. yes, first I thought about some `initialState` but the items/array could come from an `ajax` request.

Comment: So, I'll go with a composition so, in case I have an `Array` I loop inside `ADD_TODOS` like:

Comment: `ADD_TODOS` like: ...
    case 'ADD_TODOS':
      const more = action.todo.map(t => todo(t, action))
      return [
        ...state,
        ...more ];

or something similar...

Comment: Sounds about right. For AJAX, I'd dispatch an API action in componentDidMount() then return that information to your todos reducer to set up your intitial state